# Show event is not fired using bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I tried things like the followings to catch the show event for the bootbox.confirm dialog to do some css adjustments to the dialog before showing it but didn't succeed:

```
$(document).on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {...});
$(document).on("show", function (event) {...});
$(document).on("show", ".bootbox", function (event) {...});
```

How can I catch that?

Comment: If `show` is an event name in jQuery, I've really missed something.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that. You are more likely to have sucess changing whatever function is calling the modal.